# Get a sorted list in order of nearest or upcoming date first and then the rest depending on today's date

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, date

The list should be ordered in such a way that the date of the item should be near to today's date and if it has passed today's date and is still nearest then it should go to the end.
For example:

> Dates - 3/10/2017 12/9/2017 20/10/2017 21/10/2017

Assume this is the list of dates retrieved from database, when added to custom adapter will show the listview items in same sequence.
But I want them to be ordered as (considering today's date as - 18/10/2017)

> 20/10/2017 
>   21/10/2017
>   (as the upcoming dates ends in first two items, now comes the passed
>   dates list) 3/10/2017 12/9/2017

Here are the classes used,

AssignmentUpload.java

```
public AssignmentUpload(String fileName, String url, String year, String title,
                        String instructions, AttendanceDate attendanceDate, String subjectName, String uploadedBy) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.url = url;
    this.year = year;
    this.title = title;
    this.instructions = instructions;
    this.attendanceDate = attendanceDate;
    this.subjectName = subjectName;
    this.uploadedBy = uploadedBy;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getInstructions() {
    return instructions;
}

public void setInstructions(String instructions) {
    this.instructions = instructions;
}

public AttendanceDate getAttendanceDate() {
    return attendanceDate;
}

public void setAttendanceDate(AttendanceDate attendanceDate) {
    this.attendanceDate = attendanceDate;
}

public String getSubjectName() {
    return subjectName;
}

public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
    this.subjectName = subjectName;
}

public String getUploadedBy() {
    return uploadedBy;
}

public void setUploadedBy(String uploadedBy) {
    this.uploadedBy = uploadedBy;
}}
```

AttendanceDate.java is used for date

```
public class AttendanceDate implements Serializable{

private int day, month, year;

public AttendanceDate() {
}

public AttendanceDate(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

public void setDay(int day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public int getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(int month) {
    this.month = month;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AttendanceDate{" +
            "day=" + day +
            ", month=" + month +
            ", year=" + year +
            '}';
}}
```

FacultyViewAssignmentActivity.java has loadAssignmentList() function is to be edited

```
private void loadAssignmentsList() {
    pDialog.setTitle("Searching...");
    pDialog.setMessage("Enjoy Assignments... :)");
    pDialog.show();
    reference.child("assignments")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    assignmentUploadList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot ps : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : ps.getChildren()) {
                            assignmentYear.setSubjectName(ds.getValue().toString());
                            for (DataSnapshot dss : ds.getChildren()) {
                                AssignmentUpload a = dss.getValue(AssignmentUpload.class);
                                assignmentUploadList.add(a);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    assAdapter = new FacultyViewAssignmentAdapter(FacultyViewAssignmentActivity.this, assignmentUploadList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(assAdapter);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

Have stuck on this since long time, any help would be appreciated...
Thanks!

Comment: You could consider ordering your list using comparable or comparator

Comment: I'm not able to, because the data for date is not in the date format, it is simply divided into integers as int day, int month, int year.... If you could show me a better way using comparable and comparator then please... But when I tried this, month and day are getting into ascending order but the combination of them is getting shuffled..

Comment: Could you not create `LocalDate`s from those numbers? It should have factory methods for that. Then you can compare them. Something along the lines of `uploads.sort(Comparator.comparing(upload->createLocalDateFromAttDate(upload.getAttendanceDate())))`

Comment: But it will only return the list in either ascending sort or descending sort, not in the way of the nearest date first as I have explained above. @MalteHartwig

Comment: See my answer. If you use the new Comparator API, it is really easy once you know how to use it.

Comment: I would go with what MalteHartwig proposed

Comment: I have changed my answer after I finally understood what you were trying to explain about the desired ordering. You can still achieve this by using one fairly simple comparator, no need for the creation of sub lists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What if you create two sorted lists, one with upcoming dates and one with dates that have already passed. Then populate a third list first with upcoming dates and then with past dates. :-

TestCode.java

```
package com.test;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class TestCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date today = sdf.parse("18/10/2017");

        // assuming Dates - 3/10/2017 12/9/2017 20/10/2017 21/10/2017
        String dts = "3/10/2017,12/9/2017,20/10/2017,21/10/2017";

        List<AssignmentUpload> assignmentUploadList = new ArrayList<AssignmentUpload>();
        List<AssignmentUpload> futureAssg = new ArrayList<AssignmentUpload>();
        List<AssignmentUpload> pastAssg = new ArrayList<AssignmentUpload>();
        List<AssignmentUpload> finalAssg = new ArrayList<AssignmentUpload>();

        for (String dt : dts.split(",")) {

            String[] nos = dt.split("/");
            int day = Integer.parseInt(nos[0]);
            int mon = Integer.parseInt(nos[1]);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(nos[2]);

            AttendanceDate ad = new AttendanceDate(day,mon,year);
            AssignmentUpload au = new AssignmentUpload();
            au.setAttendanceDate(ad);
            au.setSubjectName("assg - " +dt);

            assignmentUploadList.add(au);

        }

        // Now we will start with assignmentUploadList

        for (AssignmentUpload au : assignmentUploadList) {

            int day = au.getAttendanceDate().getDay();
            int mon = au.getAttendanceDate().getMonth();
            int year = au.getAttendanceDate().getYear();

            Date date = sdf.parse(day+"/"+mon +"/"+year); 

            if (date.before(today)) {
                pastAssg.add(au);
            } else {
                futureAssg.add(au);
            }

        }

        // Sort pastand future dates individually
        Collections.sort(futureAssg);
        Collections.sort(pastAssg,Collections.reverseOrder());

        // Add future Dates to final Dates first
        finalAssg.addAll(futureAssg);


        // Then Add past Dates to final Dates
        finalAssg.addAll(pastAssg);

        assignmentUploadList = finalAssg;

        for (AssignmentUpload au : assignmentUploadList) {
            System.out.println(au.getSubjectName());
        }

    }

}
```

Updated AssignmentUpload.java (made it comparable)

```
package com.test;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.test.AttendanceDate;

public class AssignmentUpload implements Comparable{

    private String fileName;
    private String url;
    private String year;
    private String title;

    private String instructions;
    private AttendanceDate attendanceDate;
    private String subjectName;
    private String uploadedBy;
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }
    public void setInstructions(String instructions) {
        this.instructions = instructions;
    }
    public AttendanceDate getAttendanceDate() {
        return attendanceDate;
    }
    public void setAttendanceDate(AttendanceDate attendanceDate) {
        this.attendanceDate = attendanceDate;
    }
    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }
    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }
    public String getUploadedBy() {
        return uploadedBy;
    }
    public void setUploadedBy(String uploadedBy) {
        this.uploadedBy = uploadedBy;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {

        AssignmentUpload au = (AssignmentUpload)o;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");



        int day = attendanceDate.getDay();
        int mon = attendanceDate.getMonth();
        int year = attendanceDate.getYear();

        int oday = au.getAttendanceDate().getDay();
        int omon = au.getAttendanceDate().getMonth();
        int oyear = au.getAttendanceDate().getYear();

        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(day+"/"+mon +"/"+year);
            Date odate = sdf.parse(oday+"/"+omon +"/"+oyear);

            return date.compareTo(odate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }



}
```

Output :
assg - 20/10/2017
assg - 21/10/2017
assg - 3/10/2017
assg - 12/9/2017

Comment: Thanks, now I have my date sorted in order of future, past and then i add to final. But can you please tell me how do I update the result into my assignmentUploadList with the date's respective record simultaneously!

Comment: It looks like I was able to answer your original question. Can you mark my Answer as correct? I am looking at your code will answer shortly.

Comment: Do you want the AssignmentUpload objects in your AssignmentUploadList to be sorted in the order similar to the dates?

Comment: Yes, the question is about sorting the list by date, not getting a sorted list of the dates themselves.

Comment: @MalteHartwig The approach i have provided can be used to sort assignmentUploadList as well. (1) We will divide this assignmentUploadList into two lists one with past assignments and one with future assignments. (2) We will build two comparators to sort the Assignment Upload Objects by dates ascending and  dates descending. (3) We will sort past assignments in descending order and future assignments in ascending order (4) We will then add future and past assignments to new list. (5) Finally We will say that  assignmentUploadList = <new list that we created>

Comment: @Karan Edited my answer for assignmentUploadList

Answer (score 1):

The Comparator you need to sort dates as you wish looks like this:

```
Comparator<LocalDate> c = (date1, date2) -> {
               boolean isPast1 = date1.isBefore(LocalDate.now());
               boolean isPast2 = date2.isBefore(LocalDate.now());

               if (isPast1 != isPast2)
                   return isPast1 ? 1 : -1;

               return isPast1 ? date2.compareTo(date1) : date1.compareTo(date2);
             });
```

It sorts by first separating the dates into before and after now, and if the are in the same group, they are sorted naturally (reversed).

I described in my comment how to apply this to your uploads:

```
uploads.sort(Comparator.comparing(upload -> LocalDate.of(upload.getAttendanceDate().getYear(), upload.getAttendanceDate().getMonth(), upload.getAttendanceDate().getDay()),
             (date1, date2) -> {
                 boolean isPast1 = date1.isBefore(LocalDate.now());
                 boolean isPast2 = date2.isBefore(LocalDate.now());

                 if (isPast1 != isPast2)
                     return isPast1 ? 1 : -1;

                 return isPast1 ? date2.compareTo(date1) : date1.compareTo(date2);
             }));
```

With this you ask the list of uploads to be sorted by their date, using the comparator from above (i.e. first seaprating past and future, then ordering each group).

Comment: This is the right answer.